# Javascript Regex Pattern for Two Decimal Places

Tags: javascript, regex

```
pattern = new RegExp('([0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?|[.][0-9]{1,2})');
```

it should accept
00.00,
0.0,
00.25,
00.36,
00.56,,
222.25,
222.25,
2222.25,

should not accept
000.25,
0000.25

Comment: Should it accept 00222.25?

Comment: Should it accept 02.25?

Comment: It's funny how regex questions on Stack Overflow precipitate a contest—a race—to see who can cook up a matching regex the fastest. Most of these questions are probably duplicates in one way or another, but we race anyway, because it's fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your value can not start with a zero, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^(?:(?:0{1,2}|[1-9]\d*)?\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d*)$
```

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `0{1,2}|[1-9]\d* Match a zero 1-2 times OR digit 1-9 and 0+ times a digit
  - `)?` Close on capturing group and make it optional
  - `\.\d{1,2}` Match a dot and 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match digit 1-9 followed by 0+ times a digit
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dj9l5V/1)

If you do want to allow a leading zero, you could add matching 0+ times a zero `0*` before the second alternation:

```
^(?:(?:0{1,2}|0*[1-9]\d*)?\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d*)$
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2DlnTA/6)

Comment: @MithunS So you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/2DlnTA/3 or like this https://regex101.com/r/2DlnTA/4

Comment: @MithunS You could make the first part optional in that case https://regex101.com/r/2DlnTA/5

Comment: Where u have learnt these things? where can i learn this complex thing?

Comment: but one issue is i am not able to set this pattern in Angular Reactive Form Control :(

Comment: These are for example 2 great sites https://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: +The fourth bird: one more help it need to accept a '0' too

Comment: If you want to accept a single zero, you could add that to the alternation at the end:
https://regex101.com/r/dj9l5V/2

Comment: how to accept 01.15 ? last regex101 not allows 01.15

Comment: @MithunS For that you can take the second regex in my answer: https://regex101.com/r/2DlnTA/6

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
^(?:(?!0{3,}).*)\.\d+$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `(?:(?!0{3,}).*)` -Condition to avoid more than `2` zeros at start.
- `\.\d+` - Matches `.` followed by one or more digit.
- `$` - End of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oigsxI/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<![0-9.])((?:[0-9]{1,2}|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:[.][0-9]{1,2})?)(?![0-9.])
```

Note the *anchors* `(?<!)` and `(?!)`. You can omit the anchors if you wish but the anchors will let your pattern match even if the line contains noise other than the number. The `(?<!X)` insists that `X` not precede the match. The `(?!X)` insists that `X` not follow the match.

[If you wanted to insist that `X` did indeed precede and/or follow, then you would instead anchor with `(?<=X)` and/or `(?=X)`.]

Based on the tenor of your examples, my solution assumes that these are acceptable: 01.23; 00.23; 1.23. It assumes that these are not acceptable: 011.23; 1.234.

Comment: How will you limit Number of 0's before the '.' ?

Comment: By `[0-9]{1,2}|...` Note the 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^([0-9][1-9]+|0{0,2})\.[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**:

Before the dot `\.`, It accepts either of the two (`|`):

- `^[0-9]` the code starts with any number between 0 and 9
- `[1-9]+` then, there are as many digits between 1 and 9 as you wants

or:

- `^0{0,2}` the code starts with at most two zeros

Comment: Could you please describe the conditions that make a string accepted/rejected?

Comment: It should be in a format from 00.00 to 5000.00.
Should accept 0,0.0,00.00,.1,0.1,00.01,00.12,0125.25,4999.99,5000,5000.00 (with max length of 7 including dot[.]). Please help